# cannot add op with name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem with freeze_graph function:

> ValueError: cannot add op with name Conv1/W1/Adam as that name is already used

In this line:

```
def export_model(input_node_names, output_node_name):
    my_freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.pbtxt', None, False, 'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp', output_node_name, "save/restore_all", "save/Const:0", 'out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")
```

My model structure:

```
def get_model(input, dropout):
    with tf.name_scope('Conv1'):
        input_4D = tf.reshape(input, [-1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1])
        w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([12, 8, 1, 44], stddev=0.01), name='W1')
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([44]), name='B1')
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_4D, w1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        act1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1 + b1)
        drop1 = tf.nn.dropout(act1, dropout)
        max_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(drop1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        tf.summary.histogram('weights', w1)
        tf.summary.histogram('biases', b1)
        tf.summary.histogram('activations', act1)
        tf.summary.histogram('dropouts', drop1)

    with tf.name_scope('Conv2'):
        w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([6, 4, 44, 44], stddev=0.01), name='W2')
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([44]), name='B2')
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(max_pool1, w2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        act2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2 + b2)
        drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(act2, dropout)
        tf.summary.histogram('weights', w2)
        tf.summary.histogram('biases', b2)
        tf.summary.histogram('activations', act2)
        tf.summary.histogram('dropouts', drop2)
        conv_shape = drop2.get_shape()
        count = int(conv_shape[1] * conv_shape[2] * conv_shape[3])
        flat_output = tf.reshape(drop2, [-1, count])

    with tf.name_scope('FC'):
        w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([count, NUM_LABELS], stddev=0.01), name='W3')
        b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_LABELS]), name='B3')
        fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(flat_output, w3), b3)
        tf.summary.histogram('weights', w3)
        tf.summary.histogram('biases', b3)

    return fc
```

What did I do wrong?

P.S. Tensorflow version is 1.2.1, python version is 3.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to train/run your model and freeze it in one same graph? This could happen if you do both in the same session or script. If so, you may try starting another python script and just do the `freeze_graph`. `freeze_graph` will need to restore the model thus add ops into the graph, which already have the same ops (with the same name). That's one cause of the error.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote script in another file and imported it to my main and it worked!